# Processing a very very big data set in python - memory error

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7, data-analysis

I'm trying to process data obtained from a csv file using csv module in python. there are about 50 columns & 401125 rows in this. I used the following code chunk to put that data into a list

```
csv_file_object = csv.reader(open(r'some_path\Train.csv','rb'))
header = csv_file_object.next()
data = []
for row in csv_file_object:
    data.append(row)
```

I can get length of this list using len(data) & it returns 401125. I can even get each individual record by calling list indices. 
But when I try to get the size of the list by calling np.size(data) (I imported numpy as np) I get the following stack trace.

> MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 np.size(data)
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.pyc in size(a,
>   axis)    2198             return a.size    2199         except
>   AttributeError:
>   -> 2200             return asarray(a).size    2201     else:    2202         try:
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.pyc in asarray(a,
>   dtype, order)
>       233 
>       234     """
>   --> 235     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
>       236 
>       237 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):
>
> MemoryError:

I can't even divide that list into a multiple parts using list indices or convert this list into a numpy array. It give this same memory error.

how can I deal with this kind of big data sample. Is there any other way to process large data sets like this one.

I'm using ipython notebook in windows 7 professional.

Comment: Can you process the file [line by line as suggested in a related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6853981/1290420)?

Comment: Do you need to have  all rows in memory at once? Are you just doing one-off processing on each row? An alternative would be to make a collections.NamedTuple and convert each row into one of these tuples. They use up a really minimal amount of memory.

Comment: more rows I have in memory at once, better.
I'll try NamedTuple
Thank you

Comment: Or, if you don't need all the fields in the CSV file, only pick out the ones you need rather than adding them all to the `data`?

Comment: It looks to me like you're making a Python `list`, not a numpy `ndarray`.  So when you call `np.size`, your `list` doesn't have a `.size()` method, and `np.size` falls back on calling `asarray`, and ultimately it makes (at least) one entire other copy of your data in memory.  50x400k is not so big if it's numerical, and if so I'd use `np.loadtxt` instead of going via csv.  If your data isn't mostly numerical, there are other solutions anyway.

Comment: I kind of need all those fields & in majority of the records, values of those fields are empty, so I don't think the number of fields make a big effect on this.

Comment: only few fields are numerical

Comment: What kind of data is it then ? (if it isn't mainly numerical)
Because assuming all your data records are 64bits or less your whole dataset amount for "only" 160MBytes so it shouldn't be a problem to copy it, even several times.

More importantly your question isn't precise enough to be answered : you didn't tell us what you wanted to do with the data, which we have to know if you want to us to provide you with a solution.
As Dougal suggested Pandas library might be a very good fit for your data (again depending on what you want to do with it)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As noted by @DSM in the comments, the reason you're getting a memory error is that calling `np.size` on a list will copy the data into an array first and then get the size.

If you don't need to work with it as a numpy array, just don't call `np.size`. If you do want numpy-like indexing options and so on, you have a few options.

You could use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), which is meant for handling big not-necessarily-numerical datasets and has some great helpers and stuff for doing so.

If you don't want to do that, you could define a numpy [structure array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) and populate it line-by-line in the first place rather than making a list and copying into it. Something like:

```
fields = [('name1', str), ('name2', float), ...]
data = np.zeros((num_rows,), dtype=fields)

csv_file_object = csv.reader(open(r'some_path\Train.csv','rb'))
header = csv_file_object.next()
for i, row in enumerate(csv_file_object):
    data[i] = row
```

You could also define `fields` based on `header` so you don't have to manually type out all 50 column names, though you'd have to do something about specifying the data types for each.

Comment: There're about 50 fields and it's not easy to define a specific data type for them. So I used 'object' as the dtype so that any type can be inserted (a list of fields in this case) . This method did the job. I'll try pandas too.
Thank you