# Unexpected memory error when regriding data with scipy interpolate griddata method

Tags: python, numpy, memory-leaks, grid, scipy

I have a `3000x6000` 2D grid (from a tiff image). I want to regrid it into a lower resolution grid using `griddata` method from `scipy.interpolate` library. First, I need to form a `18000000x2` `numpy array` as the input for `griddata` based on what I read [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html). Here's what I do:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
x_length = 6000
y_length = 3000
def func(x, y):
    return x*(1-x)*np.cos(4*np.pi*x) * np.sin(4*np.pi*y**2)**2
grid_x, grid_y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1,x_length),np.linspace(0,1,y_length))
points = np.random.rand(x_length*y_length, 2)
values = func(points[:,0], points[:,1])
grid_z0 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='nearest')
```

I get a `MemoryError` when doing `griddata`. I have 8 gb of RAM and I shouldn't get this error based on the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085012/numpy-memory-error-creating-huge-matrix).

Overall, regriding a `3000x6000` grid into a lower resolution grid shouldn't be that hard and I guess I am doing something funny here. Should I get e `MemoryError` doing these liens of codes with 8 gb RAM?

P.S: Although I have a `64-bit` operating system (Windows 7), I use the following Python version:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

Comment: It works for me. I have 4 GB of RAM and more than 3 are already occupied. In fact, in htop I only see around 200 MB, and each one of your arrays is exactly 288 MB.

Comment: Also, use `x = np.round(x, 5)` to round to the first 5 decimals.

Comment: @Davidmh I edited the question a fair amount. I am still getting a `MemoryError` running the code. Do you get an error?

Comment: No, still don't get it. The usage is about 2GB.

Comment: Note that a 32-bits process can only access 4 GB.

Comment: `print (points.nbytes + values.nbytes + grid_x.nbytes + grid_y.nbytes) * 1e-6` reports 720 MB, and the final output are 144 MB more. Do you have enough free RAM?

Comment: This should give you the size of all the arrays accesible by Python: `1e-6 * sum(x.nbytes for x in globals().values() if isinstance(x, np.ndarray))`. As expected, I get the same result as before, 720 MB.

Comment: @Davidmh I get `720` MB for both of the commands that you recommended. As it turns out, reading the answer, I am not doing a very efficient thing hear in resampling the image, and at the same time, I am technically using just 2 GB of RAM since I have Python win32 on a 64 Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments point out, you run out of memory. A 32-bit Python running on 64-bit Windows 7 is limited to 2 GB of memory, and you just banged into that.

There are three solutions:

1. Get a 64-bit Python. (*suggested*)
2. Interpolate in several chunks (split the image into some suitable overlapping parts) (*laborious*)
3. Rethink your interpolation method (*recommended*)

If you have a regular grid (as in the case of an image), using `griddata` to regrid it into another regular grid is quite wasteful in terms of memory and time.

There are several methods to downsample the image. At least `PIL` and `cv2` modules offer downsampling functions. If you want to use a SciPy method, have a look at `scipy.ndimage.zoom`. It will allow you to resample the image from one regular grid to another.

Comment: I will definitely change my Python to `64-bit`. It was useful to know I am only using 2 GB of my RAM!

If I already have a 2D numpy array (2D grid) and don't have access to the tiff file anymore, what is the most efficient way to do it? Do you think using `RegularGridInterpolator` from `scipy.interpolate` would be a good option?

Comment: If you have the image data in a 2D array, then the easiest way is to use something like `scipy.ndimage.zoom(my_img_array, 0.43)` to scale both directions by 0.43 (or whatever you want).