# Effecient way of defining data types for very large structured arrays in python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working with Numpy arrays on python to process  distance matrices produced by clustal omega application , bu I'm having troubles reading and creating very large structured numpy arrays with different data types .

I managed to work around the problem , but I'm here to ask for the correct way to do it .

The main problem was the difficulty of declaring the data type for each individual column in the matrix of 9726 x 9726 dimensions .

Here's the code snippet I wrote to force the format I need for the output matrix to be further manipulated :

```
for i in range(len(fasta_files)):
    global No
    inFile = open(fasta_files[i],'r')
    headerCount = 0
    for line in inFile:
        if line[0] == ">":
            headerCount +=1
    No = headerCount
    name=fasta_files[i][:fasta_files[i].find(".")]
    output_handle = open("$"+fasta_files[i],"w")
    new_IDs=[]
    for idx,record in enumerate(SeqIO.parse(fasta_files[i],"fasta",IUPAC.unambiguous_dna)):
        record.id=record.id+"_"+str(idx+1)
        new_IDs.append(record.id) 
        SeqIO.write(record,output_handle,"fasta")
    output_handle.close()
    new_IDs=np.array(new_IDs)
    data=np.genfromtxt(name+'.dst')
    data=np.array(data,dtype=object)
    data[:,0]=new_IDs
    np.savetxt(name+".dst",data,delimiter=" ",fmt='%s '+'%f '*No)
```

What I'm trying to do is reading data from a space delimited distance matrix of the following format , update the ID based on `new_IDs` contents (by adding the sequence No. in the file to avoid duplicates ahead ) and overwrite it with the same file name .

```
Traes_2BL_B2871DAAB.1 100.000000 21.944035 22.133939 23.723042 19.750284 20.431328 20.885358 21.679909
Traes_7BL_26A3CC41D.1 21.944035 100.000000 22.827688 21.796760 22.974963 20.324006 21.944035 24.889543
Traes_5AL_DE0E4DC71.1 22.133939 22.827688 100.000000 21.152030 22.474032 17.387033 19.830028 20.963173
Traes_2BS_D7A73A455.2 23.723042 21.796760 21.152030 100.000000 20.437018 24.361493 19.059107 19.436957
OS01T0101800-01       19.750284 22.974963 22.474032 20.437018 100.000000 21.414538 20.094259 21.765210
OS01T0103000-01       20.431328 20.324006 17.387033 24.361493 21.414538 100.000000 20.432220 20.432220
OS01T0103050-01       20.885358 21.944035 19.830028 19.059107 20.094259 20.432220 100.000000 19.018898
OS01T0103600-01       21.679909 24.889543 20.963173 19.436957 21.765210 20.432220 19.018898 100.000000
```

The output is expected to be like this :

```
Traes_2BL_B2871DAAB.1_1 100.000000 21.944035 22.133939 23.723042 19.750284 20.431328 20.885358 21.679909
Traes_7BL_26A3CC41D.1_2 21.944035 100.000000 22.827688 21.796760 22.974963 20.324006 21.944035 24.889543
Traes_5AL_DE0E4DC71.1_3 22.133939 22.827688 100.000000 21.152030 22.474032 17.387033 19.830028 20.963173
Traes_2BS_D7A73A455.2_4 23.723042 21.796760 21.152030 100.000000 20.437018 24.361493 19.059107 19.436957
OS01T0101800-01_5       19.750284 22.974963 22.474032 20.437018 100.000000 21.414538 20.094259 21.765210
OS01T0103000-01_6       20.431328 20.324006 17.387033 24.361493 21.414538 100.000000 20.432220 20.432220
OS01T0103050-01_7       20.885358 21.944035 19.830028 19.059107 20.094259 20.432220 100.000000 19.018898
OS01T0103600-01_8       21.679909 24.889543 20.963173 19.436957 21.765210 20.432220 19.018898 100.000000
```

As you can see from the code above , I repeated the format specifier No. times which represents the dimensions of each  single matrix on running time , obviously I cant define a 9726 format specifier of float type by hand !!

The used approach is not efficient as it forces the loop to calculate the number of sequences in each fasta file , so it can be used later for the structured numpy array format specifier but this decreases the efficiency and speed of my algorithm .

I spent a lot of time on the internet looking for a good solution , I found some useful threads but none of them met my exact case :(

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/numpy/fv_tfDldihs) was the inspiration of the work around I used earlier , and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551451/processing-a-very-very-big-data-set-in-python-memory-error) was helpful too beside many [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309739/store-different-datatypes-in-one-numpy-array) ... but I need to do it in the correct way and nothing seems to tackle my specific issue .

So , **My question is** : How can I define a structured array  with a string type first column and a float type 9726 other different unique columns ?! (please note that dimensions varies and are not of fixed size).

Any help would be highly appreciated , thanks in advance ...

Comment: Did you consider Pytables (http://ww.pytables.org)? It is designed to work with large amounts of data.

Comment: @Dietrich ... Actually , I was about to do so but since my matrices are not larger than 10000 x 10000 dimensions as claimed by this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053928/very-large-matrices-using-python-and-numpy) , I hesitated to do so !! But that wasn't my issue though .

Comment: Are you trying to make a 2D array with shape `(N,N)`, or a 1D array of shape `(N,)` with a `dtype` that has `N` fields?  Do all columns/fields have the same type except the first?

Comment: @hpaulj...yes , it's of shape (N,N) , and yes all columns but the first are of float data type . Actually I got confused by your comment , I thought that my array is of N dimensions !! So , you're saying that multidimensional arrays are always 2D arrays with shape (N,N) ?!